# How can I put 2 collectionViews in a single ViewController?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I have this code to make a UICollectionView with in another ViewController:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return tvSeries.count
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let identifier = "Item"
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: identifier, for: indexPath) as! SeriesCollectionViewCell
    cell.itemLabel.text = tvSeries[indexPath.row]
    cell.itemImage.image = UIImage.init(imageLiteralResourceName: tvSeries[indexPath.row])

    return cell
}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    let item = sender as? UICollectionViewCell
    let indexPath = collectionView.indexPath(for: item!)
    let detailVC = segue.destination as! DetailViewController
    detailVC.detailName = tvSeries[(indexPath?.row)!]
}
```

I want to have a ViewController with 2 CollectionViews like in this picture:

[image: example]

Comment: So whats the problem ?

Comment: Get outlet of your two collectionView control.When ever your datasource & delegate methods are fired check condition based on collection view object from  method.Something like if collectionView == self.firstCV {}

Answer (score 2):

In your collectionView functions such as `numberOfItemsInSection`, check if the `collectionView` argument is equal to one or the other collection view and then return the number as required.

For example, if you had the following IBOutlets:

```
@IBOutlet weak var collectionViewOne: UICollectionView!
@IBOutlet weak var collectionViewTwo: UICollectionView!
```

then your `numberOfItemsInSection` would change to:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if collectionView == collectionViewOne {
        return itemSource1.count
    }
    else {
        return itemSource2.count
    }
}
```

Do the same for the rest of the collectionView functions.